# Risk of "attachToTangle" enabled on remote iri?

Tags: iri-node

If I have attachToTangle enabled in my iri.ini config file, then can people send transactions to my server and my server will do proof of work for them?

This seems like I could be taken advantage of.

How do I allow only myself to do attachToTangle and no one from the abyss of the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API call “attachToTangle” (and others) are DDOS risks and could result in a lot of resources being tied-up if people try to abuse them.

If you are local to your own node, (ie on the same network ;localhost;) then you don't need to enable this in the API for outside connections.

Just make sure to specify the flag in remoteLimitAPI (check that name in the -help).